# Embarrassing questions should be moved under anonymous Stack Overflow Account as per OP will

Tags: feature-request, bad-questions, disassociation

I request the feature to move embarrassing questions asked by any one to Stack Overflow's personal account.
Lets call that account stackoverflow or stackoverflow_user or anonymous or choose any other generic user name.

Many times we developers ask some dumb/embarrassing questions, and many other so talented people start insulting the OP.
Reason of asking a dumb/silly questions can be many, he simply might have forgotten the concepts or the solution did not hit his brain at the moment or lets say he is really a dumb or bad developer even then do not block his chance of trying to improve and grow.

Unfortunately such questions remain attached to the OP account, and any one can see and conclude or say miss-conclude that this particular person is totally dumb.
Important:
With the addition of Job search and apply feature to stackoverflow if recruiter will visit applicant's SO profile, it may put vary very negative impact on the recruiter, the applicant may not get any interview call at all.

Lets not forget that SO was not created for recruiters or with intention to earn money, but to help Developers.

Above is applicable to all those questions which can not be deleted by OP and Stack Overflow will not delete those because of the reason "People have invested time on it"

So OKAY don't delete just move these to Stack Overflow's very own generic user account.
This way questions and associated replies/answers will still be accessible to every one.

Please provide a button, OP will simply click on it and the question will move to anonymous account, it should be that easy.

Comment: What improvement should that gain? Automatically anonymize users who aren't warranted here?

Comment: We are here to create and curate good content. Delegating a junkyard for garbage when it should be incinerated or landfilled helps no-one.

Comment: Who told to automatically anonymize ???
I tried deleting one of my question and SO denied because of the reason "others have invested time and effort in answering it"

Comment: I've got one of these, it's at -20.    So what?  If you have lots of good contributions, the odd cockup just makes you look human:)

Comment: @MartinJames, I disagree, if you are hunting for a job, that -ve may bite you.

Comment: @Sumit if it does, I don't want that job:)

Comment: @MartinJames, okay, good for you, but they won't tell you probably, so you will never know, what really happened.

Comment: I hope one day all the down-voters will need this feature, Good Bye.

Comment: If the questions you've asked are really *so* bad, and reflect so poorly on your programming ability that they'd dissuade people from giving you a job, then maybe you're not actually qualified for the job you're seeking.

Comment: This seems like a *fantastic* way to allow new users to bypass the automated question ban.  Just anonymize it, and keep asking bad questions, never to be stopped.

Comment: @fbueckert In theory you could anomomize what's show publicly and still keep them tied behind the scenes.  In fact that it's not done for anonomized posts now is simply wrong in my opinion.

Comment: @Servy In theory, sure.  But I can guarantee what would happen if it didn't: people would complain even more about hitting a question ban, and since they've anonymized some of their posts, they won't be visible to them anymore.  It's just one more way for users in the ban to hide those inconvenient posts that didn't get a good reception.  And require more community and mod workload to surface them so they can not fix them.  The value of this is going to be extremely minimal, if there's any at all.

Comment: @fbueckert Is having anonimized posts still affecting your post ban any worse than deleted questions you can't find still affecting your post ban?  I'm not saying this feature is worth the effort, I'm just saying you can do it without creating an exploit for post banned users.

Comment: Depends on the tooling to expose the anonymized posts, @Servy.  The idea behind anonymization is exactly that; it shouldn't be tied to you anymore.  To me, that implies that the consequences of the post shouldn't follow, either, nor the ability to have them surfaced for you to have to fix.  Which you can already see people doing by deleting and recreating accounts in order to bypass restrictions.  [This notable example comes to mind.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327498/193762)

Comment: Rather than try and hide you mistakes, I suggest you improve from them. Showing your early failures next to your (hopefully) recent successes is a great indication that you learn and grow from your mistakes. That is an invaluable quality in any employee. Just some food for thought, I know it's a bit of a tangent.

Answer (score 20):

No.

Address the insults where ever they are. Flags can be used for that. Moderators will handle that.

Just for the record: Down votes and close votes are not insults.

What bothers me most at your request is the *at will*. So that basically also opens up creative opportunities for:

- quality banned users
- homework cheaters
- plagiarism
- spam

And all these problems could cause havoc only because an OP fears it might hurt their career opportunity. And I have not (yet) seen a confession from a single recruiter that they only select candidates with a positive SO profile. We all have scratches. Nothing to be afraid of.

Fear is a bad argument for making changes to any system. Let's keep the embarrassing questions.

Comment: I disagree, because all those 4 points can always be achieved through brand new fake SO account.

Comment: @Sumit I suggest you try that to find out you can't. At least not once you start to become active with these accounts.

Comment: also I think people overestimate the interest of recruiters for stackoverflow accounts.

Comment: @rene I think you overestimate how much the types of people who get post banned value building an account, earning reputation (both the Imaginary Internet Points and the more general "opinion people have of you" variety), having moderation privileges, etc.  Being able to make new accounts to ask new questions is more than enough for most of the types of users that end up post banned.

Comment: @Servy yeah, I've definitely seen (OK, technically *suspect* I've seen) people making a new account per question. However, the same users who don't care about accounts also wouldn't care about "anonymising" their old questions. Why should they - they don a new identity anyway. As for the rest, rene is right - insults should be dealt with directly by mods. Simply running away from them is not a good solution. And OP is...quite misguided, I think. If you ask a question so simple to (apparently) earn the ire of SO, then this seems like a bad question you shouldn't have posted but researched first

Answer (score 17):

Here's a simpler approach.

## Flag all of the comments which go out of their way to insult the OP.

Those comments add *no* value and serve *no* purpose. What's better is that this is already built, so we don't have to add more plumbing in to address what is already a well-addressed circumstance.

Comment: Please tell me the way to use that feature

Comment: Every answer has a "flag" link.  Every comment has a little "flag" icon on them.  Not sure what else needs to be said, really.

Comment: That flag needs around more than 50 votes(as it showed for my question)

Comment: Therefore the feature is not really implemented so that it will be in OP's hand.

Comment: There is no digital lever you can pull to absolve yourself from "embarrassment". What *can* be done is remove the harassment, which is the main objective anyway.

Comment: I am proposing that such digital lever should be created, its a feature request.
And I believe its not impossible.

Comment: Hi, welcome back!

Comment: @Sumit but your suggested change seems to not be very good for the site or its ongoing quality. People explain to you the worries they have with this feature, how it could be bad. You're not addressing any of the concerns. That, unfortunately, will likely mean your Feature will never lift off. Not to say I think it was a good feature necessarily... but if you thought it was, then addressing these concerns is likely your best bet

Answer (score 11):

Embarrassing questions are often bad, so downvoted/closed.

- OP (original poster) can then choose to delete them. An employer visiting OP profile cannot stumble on them (unless he's a moderator, but that would not be fair/ethical and would be also very unlikely :))
- OP can edit them to improve them (without changing the meaning / defacing as it sometimes happens) fixing typos, clarifying them, to make them look better and less "noobish"

Sometimes OP accepts the answer, and then flags for deletion when there aren't any upvotes. In that case, just unaccept, and delete the post. Done.

If OP cannot delete (because there are upvoted answers), it's still possible to custom flag the post for:

- deletion (a moderator must evaluate if the upvoted answers are good enough to preserve or not)
- post dissociation from their account. This involves community managers (standard moderators can't do that themselves) but it's standard procedure. See [What are the conditions for a dissociation and how does it impact the post-ban system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225986/what-are-the-conditions-for-a-dissociation-and-how-does-it-impact-the-post-ban-s)

So you see, plenty of options already. The feature you're asking for already exists. It's "delete" or "flag / in need of moderator intervention". Granted, the flag can be denied, but with good arguments, I don't see why it would.

Comment: "unless he's a moderator, but that would not be fair and would be also very unlikely" Using moderator only information to affect hiring decisions at another job would be violating the moderator rules, would it not?

Comment: it would not be fair, and unethical too, yes. Of course if you're applying for an SO job, the employees can still do that, I guess. I would not do that. Let deleted posts remain deleted.